# Transition_Post_Status hook not working properly

Tags: hooks, post-status

When I run this code, the `$cptnumber` variable doesn't receive the custom post type number when I set a published post to draft. (For example: 367)

It works when I trash a post, but not when I change one to draft.  Any idea how to fix this?

```
function publish_to_anything( $new_status, $old_status, $post_id ){
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );
    $cptnumber = get_the_id($post_id);

    if( $post_type == 'exp' && $old_status == 'publish'){

        require_once('page-run_when_cpt_unpublished.php');
    }


}   

add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'publish_to_anything', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by “custom post number”? What should `get_the_id( $post_id )` return - what’s your intention for this part of code?

Comment: I am trying to get the post number. For example, when you create a new custom post (or just a new post), there is a post number assigned to it. Your first post is #1, your second is #2, etc..

Comment: Post number? WordPress assigns only IDs to posts... (but they are only autoincrement column in DB). Is that what you mean?

Comment: That could be it. Whenever you hover over a post to edit it, the number assigned to it is in the edit URL.

Comment: That's the post ID, which you've already got in the `$post_id` parameter. You don't need to use `get_the_ID()` (which only appears to work in The Loop, besides). Just replace `$cptnumber` with `$post_id`.

Comment: Also note that it's `get_the_ID()`, not `get_the_id()`. Generally speaking, PHP is case-sensitive.